# Filtering/Returning a single nested object from mongo returned object (findOne)

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor, ecmascript-6

Although there are questions on here surrounding the subject, I'm yet to find a clear versatile "best practice" for filtering through a returned meteor mongo collection object.

(FYI: I'm using MeteorJS)

I've pulled a configuration document from a configs collection.

```
let thisConfig = ClinicConfigs.findOne({_id: "xyz"});
```

this has returned the following

```
{
    _id: "xyz",
    name: "john doe's clinic",
    activeServices: [
         {
             name: "teeth whitening",
             ref: "teethWhitening",
             docs: [
                 {
                     docId: "a",
                     name: "Client questionnaire",
                     ref: "clientQuestionnaire",
                 },
                 {
                     docId: "b",
                     name: "Client consent form",
                     ref: "clientConsentForm",
                 }
             ]
         },
         {
             name: "liposuction",
             ref: "liposuction",
             docs: [
                 {
                     docId: "a",
                     name: "Client questionnaire",
                     ref: "clientQuestionnaire",
                 },
                 {
                     docId: "b",
                     name: "Client consent form",
                     ref: "clientConsentForm",
                 }
             ]
         }
    ];
```

Once i've returned this document/object I need to pull just one object from the activeServices array.

Although this doesn't work, here's the logic to clarify what I need:

```
let thisService = ClinicConfigs.findOne({_id: "xyz"})
        .activeServices.findOne({ref: "teethWhitening"});
```

I tried the following but didn't get any success:

```
let thisConfig = ClinicConfigs.findOne({_id: "xyz"});
let thisService = thisConfig.activeServices.filter(function(d) {return d.ref === "teethWhitening"})[0];

return thisService.docs;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works but i had to correct your thisConfig data object with a trailing braces. So once it is like

```
var thisCongig = {
    _id: "xyz",
    name: "john doe's clinic",
    activeServices: [
         {
             name: "teeth whitening",
             ref: "teethWhitening",
             docs: [
                 {
                     docId: "a",
                     name: "Client questionnaire",
                     ref: "clientQuestionnaire",
                 },
                 {
                     docId: "b",
                     name: "Client consent form",
                     ref: "clientConsentForm",
                 }
             ]
         },
         {
             name: "liposuction",
             ref: "liposuction",
             docs: [
                 {
                     docId: "a",
                     name: "Client questionnaire",
                     ref: "clientQuestionnaire",
                 },
                 {
                     docId: "b",
                     name: "Client consent form",
                     ref: "clientConsentForm",
                 }
             ]
         }
    ]
};
var thisService = data.activeServices.find( d => d.ref == "teethWhitening");
```

And it is retrieved.

Comment: The end brace was a typo on my part when typing the question.  your solution works isolated but not when used within my Meteor helper function.  This leads me to believe that this is a timing issue.   Thanks for your help, i've now ruled out the functions I was using!